# Kotlin generates SAM stubs inconsistencely

Tags: kotlin, functional-interface

For example, I've got a functional interface:

```
public interface SomeInt<R, P> {
    R execute(P param);
}
```

Later I want to pass it as a parameter, so I'm creating inline implementation

```
//implementation 1
val someInt = SomeInt { id: Int? -> "param $id" }
//implementation 2
val someFun = { id: Int? -> "param $id" }
val someInt2: SomeInt<String, Int> = SomeInt(someFun)
```

The code above generates two different implementations
I'm not sure where to look at, but that's what caught my eye:

```
println(someInt.javaClass.name)
println(someInt2.javaClass.name)
println(someInt.javaClass.methods.filter { it.name == "execute" }.map { "${it.name}  ${it.returnType}  ${it.parameterTypes.map { it.name }} ${it.parameters[0].name}\n" })
println(someInt2.javaClass.methods.filter { it.name == "execute" }.map { "${it.name}  ${it.returnType}  ${it.parameterTypes.map { it.name }} ${it.parameters[0].name}\n" })
```

output is:

```
my.test.TestKt$main$someInt$1
my.test.TestKt$sam$my_test_SomeInt$0
[execute  class java.lang.String  [java.lang.Integer] arg0
, execute  class java.lang.Object  [java.lang.Object] arg0
]
[execute  class java.lang.Object  [java.lang.Object] arg0
]
```

Why do both implementations generate totally different bytecode? I thought that at least the amount of method overloads should be the same

Comment: Why do you expect it to be the same?  One is a class specifically implemented to implement `SomeInt`; the other accepts a Kotlin function object and uses it to implement `SomeInt`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman So, you mean that type information is lost when creating function object, so the only overload actually present is Object -> Object?

Comment: Any object that implements SomeInt will, at minimum, get a bridge method accepting and returning Object.